# Pick a random result that hasnt been displayed

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

Anyone who could help me it will be greatly appreciated.

Goal: I want to display the id from one table randomly as well as to make sure it has not been seen by the current user.

Two tables: `offers`,  `has_seen`

I want to pick a random id from offers, check it against the has_seen table.

If the ID exists in the has_seen, it need to re pick another random id. The same ID should never be seen by any one user of the current session.

I cannot seem to figure out how to pick a random one, check the other table, and loop back if found.

I have tried this

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM ".$this->offer_table." WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM ".$this->shown_table." WHERE ".$this->shown_table.".camp_id = ".$this->offer_table.".camp_id AND ".$this->shown_table.".usercode = ".$this->session->userdata("table")." LIMIT 1 ");
```

Comment: I have tried this: `$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM ".$this->offer_table."  WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM ".$this->shown_table." WHERE ".$this->shown_table.".camp_id = ".$this->offer_table.".camp_id AND ".$this->shown_table.".usercode = ".$this->session->userdata("table")." LIMIT 1 ");` and yes I am using codeigniter but straight mysql will be okay.

Answer (score 1):

I think that this can be achieved in plain SQL by doing a left join and then checking for null.

Something along the lines of

```
SELECT * FROM table1 LEFT JOIN table2 USING (shared_key) WHERE table2.id IS NULL ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1
```

Comment: I get a Unknown column 'ya2x8' in 'where clause', although i doubled check its there.

Comment: Can you add your table structure to your question please.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you could do it using CI's db class:

```
 // the maximum ID that is acceptable
$max = $this->db->get('first_table')->count();

while(true) {
    // get a random number
    $randomID = rand(0,$max);

    // the condition for which we will check the has_seen table
    $condition = array(
        'id' => $randomID
    );

    // if count is 0, it has not been seen. We add it to the table and return
    // if it has been seen, the loop will repeat
    if ($this->db->get_where('has_seen', $condition)->count() === 0) {
        $this->db->insert('has_seen', array(
            'id' => $randomID
        ));
        return $randomID;
    }
}
```

Comment: interesting after putting your code in i get: `Fatal error: Call to undefined method CI_DB_mysql_result::count()`, and i autoload the db class in the autoconfig

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM `offers` WHERE `camp_id` NOT IN (SELECT `camp_id` FROM `has_seen` WHERE `user code` = 1) ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
```

Comment: after editing to match my tables I get a Unknown column 'ya2x8' in 'where clause', although i doubled check its there

Answer (score 0):

I always prefer reading the contents of a table into an array and working with them from there.  Depending on how you plan to use the results, you could cut down on db accesses by reading it all only once and then serving from the array (and then, I presume, updating the has_seen table for next session).

I must apologize for the pseudocode as it's been years since I've written any PHP.

Once you've got your array, the algorithm looks like this:

```
var array
var end = array.length

function getNextRandomUnseen
{
  var i = rand(end)
  var temp = array[i]
  array[i] = array[end--]
  return temp
}
```

If you want, you can even stick the seen values at the end of the array so they aren't lost.

```
array[end+1] = temp
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers. I redid the way it is going to be brought to the user and believe the new way is much more efficient when it comes to hundreds of people on my site at once.

Thanks!